# Default editing commands not working in TextBox when filtering KeyPress

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a textbox in my winform in which after puting a validation using regex on keypress event, the default functionalities like copy paste etc of the textbox is not working.

How can i handle this?

Regex used code

```
private void textbox_keypress(object sender,keypresseventargs e)
    {
        var regex= new regex(@"^[0-9,]*$");
        if(!regex.ismatch(e.keychar.tostring()))
            {
                e.handled=true;
            }
    }
```

after removing the keypress event handler everything is working fine but i have to restrict user to enter comma separated number value and also copy paste delete backspace in that textbox.

Comment: You're not the best copy/paster, are you?

Comment: You probably also want *Select All* and *Undo*, don't you?

Comment: Yes all the default functionalities of textbox as after using keypress event all these are not working

Comment: Whether it is a good idea or not, you'd be better of using the `TextChanged` event and create a regex that validates the entire input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ctrl-Commands don't work because you abort their entries. To avoid this you must **either**

- check if the Ctrl-Key has been pressed. The `KeyPress` event doesn't tell you that. This [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) from MSDN shows you how to do it: You script the `KeyDown` event to set (or clear) a flag variable, which you can then test in the `KeyPress`. No, not exactly elegant imho, but that's how MS tells you to do it.. (Note that I have added the Backspace code \b, as it isn't covered by the Ctrl-check..)

---

```
  bool ctrlPressed = false;

  private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
      ctrlPressed = (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control);
  }

  private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
  {
     if (!ctrlPressed) 
     { 
        var regex= new Regex(@"^[0-9,\b]*$");
        if (!regex.IsMatch(e.KeyChar.ToString()))
        {
           e.Handled = true;
        }
     }
  }
```

- **Or**, if you want better control over which Ctrl-Keys are allowed, skip the whole flags-affair and instead simply include them one by one in the allowed keys-brackets like this for ^C, ^X, ^A, ^V ^Z etc..:

---

```
var regex= new Regex(@"^[0-9,\b\cC\cX\cA\cV\cZ]*$");
```

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/4edbef7e%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is the description from MSDN:

> \cX   Matches an ASCII control character, where X is the letter of the
>   control character. For example, \cC is CTRL-C.

On a side note: The old fashioned copy&paste commands of Ctl-Ins and Shift-Ins work as normal even in your original code.

Comment: yes this has solved copy paste cut issue but backspace and select all is still not working...

Comment: See my new version; I think simply including all Ctrl-Keys you want to work is the better solution.

Comment: Yes this regex solution is most effective way...but still ctrl+A is not working

Comment: Now that _is weird_! It works just fine here! These must be something else going on..  If you can't find out, maybe this will help:         `private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        { if (Control.ModifierKeys == Keys.Control &&  e.KeyCode == Keys.A)  { textBox1.SelectAll(); e.Handled = true; }`